# Power switching circuit: MOSFET related query

Tags: power, mosfet, circuit-design

We are building a device which has two modes of operation. The device is to be used in an automobile.

The first mode is powered through the car's 12 V supply. For the second mode, the device has an internal 12v Li-ion battery to power the components.

Where we are stuck is: how to prevent the power from the internal battery to be supplied to the components in the first mode and also to switch easily between the power sources during mode switch as and when required?

What electrical components could be used on the PCB to do so, and can this be done with the help of MOSFETs?

Comment: Look into load switches or ideal diode controllers.

Comment: to add to Hearth's comment, sometimes they're also called "power supply ORing controllers"

Comment: Power path controllers is another phrase maybe [this device might be useful](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/4412hvfs.pdf)

Comment: How about using a PNP transistor? Will it be useful?

Comment: What will be the load current of your device?